# videos loaded on the website displays only on safari but not on other browsers

Tags: browser

the videos only display in Safari but not on other browsers, how do I get them to display on all browsers?

```
<div class="row row-0-gutter">
            <!-- start portfolio item -->
            <div class="col-md-6 col-0-gutter">
                <div class="ot-portfolio-item">
                    <figure class="effect-bubba">
                        <img src="videos/defensea.mp4" alt="img" class="img-responsive" />
                        <figcaption>
                            <h2>Defense Tech</h2>
                            <p>Systems, Solutions, Supplies</p>
                            <a href="http://defense.jbwlimited.com" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="">View more</a>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end portfolio item -->
```

Comment: Hello, Welcome to Stackoverflow. Are you getting any error or exception? It will help the users to help you. Currently, its little vague. You need to provide some more details. Add error or exception log or if it is on github post github url for reference.

Comment: Hi, thank you. no I do not think im getting errors or exceptions

Comment: Did you check developer tools of browser?If not, then you have to provide some more details. It's difficult to figure out the exact problem on the basis of the information you provided.